# metasploit+openvas error

Tags: metasploit, openvas

switched to openvas a couple days, is open and does the job.. so far so good, but I hit a wall.. with metasploit I load the module, I log in, fine.. but when I run some tasks I get some errors.. I think the plugin needs to be update..

```
> openvas_report_import 2 NBE
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb:102:in `sendrecv': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
[*] Importing report to database.
```

Seems like nobody is maintaining the code for openvas plugin? anyone has experienced this? if I sed that file for the timeout objet and sed it to Timeout.timeout will it work?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so I went ahead and did try and that seem to have worked
now no error.

```
msf > openvas_report_import 2 14
[*] Importing report to database.
msf >
```

so

```
vim /usr/share/metasploit/lib/openvas/openvas-omp.rb
```

and change the line where  timeout to Timeout.timeout

```
openvas]$ ruby -c openvas-omp.rb 
Syntax OK
```